# How to trigger 'CTRL + S' keyboard shortcut to save input data on Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm new in blazor and I'm working on a form which allows users to input data on it. Currently, these data are saved through a save button, but I'm looking to add "CTRL + S" as another alternative for saving. Is there a way to do that?

I've tried the keyboard events but I can't make it work, instead it always ends up with the default browser behavior to save the page.

Here's my code:

```
<EditForm Model=@user OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <p>
        <label for="displayName" class="form-label">
            Display Name:
        </label>
        <InputText class="form-control" id="displayName" @bind-Value="user.DisplayName" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="firstName" class="form-label">
            First Name:
        </label>
        <InputText class="form-control" id="firstName" @bind-Value="user.FirstName" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="lastName" class="form-label">
            Last Name:
        </label>
        <InputText class="form-control" id="lastName" @bind-Value="user.LastName" />
    </p>

    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" @onclick="_navigateToUsersList">Cancel</button>
</EditForm>



@code {

    private User user = new();

    private void _navigateToUsersList() => Navigation.NavigateTo(@"users");

    private async void HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        // code when save button is clicked
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an event listener to the document object in your component's OnAfterRender method to capture the keydown event:

```
    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("addEventListener", "keydown", "handleKeyDown");
        }
    }
```

Define a JavaScript function handleKeyDown that checks whether the Ctrl and S keys were pressed, and if so, calls the Save method:

```
    window.handleKeyDown = (event) => {
        if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 83) {
            event.preventDefault();
            save();
        }
    };
```

or

Add a reference to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web namespace in your Blazor component.

In the component's OnInitialized method, register an event listener for the keydown event of the document object. This will allow you to handle all keyboard events that occur on the page.

```
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Register an event listener for the "keydown" event of the document object
        document.AddEventListener("keydown", HandleKeyDown);
    }
```

In the event listener method (HandleKeyDown), check if the Ctrl key and S key were both pressed. If they were, prevent the default behavior of the event (which would be to scroll the page), and then trigger a click event on the form's Save button.

```
    private void HandleKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if the Ctrl key and S key were both pressed
        if (e.CtrlKey && e.Key == "s")
        {
            // Prevent the default behavior of the event
            e.PreventDefault();
    
            // Trigger a click event on the form's Save button
            saveButton.Click();
        }
    }
```

In your Blazor component's @code block, define a reference to the form's Save button using the @ref directive.

```
    <form>
        <!-- Input fields go here -->
        <button @onclick="Save" @ref="saveButton">Save</button>
    </form>
    
    @code {
        private ElementReference saveButton;
    
        private void Save()
        {
            // Save the form data
        }
    }
```

With these changes, pressing Ctrl + S anywhere on the page will trigger a click event on the form's Save button, which will save the form data.

Comment: How are you referencing the document in the OnInitialized function? I didn't think this was possible.